# converting a string of tags into a dict in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, dictionary, tags

I have a string, which isn't really XML, but appears just to be a list of tags. Nothing is hierarchical. I just want to get out a dict of key/value pairs.

The string just has tags that start with `tag name` and end with `value`. It looks like this:

```
str = '<tag name="image_num_t" value="1"/><tag name="image_pixel_depth" type='A' value="6"/>'
```

I'd like to create a dict like this:

```
d = {'image_num' : 1, 'image_pixel_depth':6}
```

(No need for `type` or anything)

This looks like a pretty decent pain to code up from scratch, and also feels unnecessary. I looked at a variety of packages (like lxlm, etc) thinking maybe I could transform it into proper XML then parse it like a mature adult, but nothing works.

Can anyone advise me on the best way to convert a string of tags into a dict using python 2.7? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing missing from your string to be qualified as XML is a root element, as shown in question, then the fix should be as easy as adding a temporary root element. From this point you can use any XML parser to extract the information and store it in dictionary :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

str = '''<tag name="image_num_t" value="1"/><tag name="image_pixel_depth" type='A' value="6"/>'''
source = '<root>' + str + '</root>'

root = ET.fromstring(source)
d = {t.attrib['name']: int(t.attrib['value']) for t in root.findall('tag')}
```

test: https://eval.in/928392

Comment: Thanks...I'll check this out in depth after the weekend. much appreciated